# cannot log into my Canopy acct

Tags: enthought

Hi fellow users of Enthought Canopy.

I just installed and launched Enthought Canopy. At the "Welcome to Canopy" window, I clicked on "Log into your Enthought", but I keep getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to authenticate your login. Please check internet connection (or proxy configuration if applicable) Error: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Can someone help? I am using Canopy on my work laptop, so I'm guessing that may be the reason the SSL is not working?

Answer (score 1):

From the message, it's likely that your workplace uses a proxy firewall. See the article ["Using Canopy Behind a Proxy Firewall"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469150-Can-I-use-Canopy-Behind-a-Proxy-Firewall-).